steps to clone a salesforce object
I'm having a requirement, that i already have a salesforce project in a developer edition org, i want to create a new developer edition org, and copy all the object, layout, everything from that existing org to the new org, and some new additions to the project such that it won't be reflected in the existing org, how can i do, Any solution is welcomed because it'll be of a great help to me, and thanks in advance.

See this Salesforce DevOps page for tool options for this. The general approach is to retrieve from one org to your computer and then deploy to another org; no need to use Git to start with.

There are also excellent vendor DevOps tools like Copado & Gearset that don't relay on VCS (although support VCS just fine)
